# Работа с регулярными выражениями в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть код, работа лишь с данными в файле.

```
import re

f = open('12345')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open('12345', 'w')
for line in lines:
    r = re.search(r'^.*("deactivated":"banned"|"deactivated":"deleted").*$', line).group(0)
    if line != r:
        f.write(line)
        print(r)
f.close()
```

Проблема заключается в следующем. Нужно чтобы выдавал в "r" точную строку, это я делаю с помощью ".group(0)", но как только находится исключение, "r" становится объектом "None", всё крашится. Пробовал:

```
try:
    if line != r:
        f.write(line)
        print(r)
except AttributeError:
    continue
```

Без результатов. Ни в какую не хочет перехватывать ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Регулярку, кстати, можно упростить: `r'"deactivated":"(banned|deleted)"'`.

Comment: И `.group(0)` делать совсем ни к чему - достаточно сравнить r с None, вас же факт отсутствия совпадения интересует, None именно это и означает: `if re.search(r'"deactivated":"(banned|deleted)"') == None`

Comment: В идеале мне нужен факт сравнения строки, а потом уже с "None". Вы подсказали правильное решение, регулярку можно отбросить, до поры.

Comment: Собственно, непосредственно ошибка заключается в том, что строку `try` надо перенести на 1 строчку выше: `try: r=re.searc(...).group(0)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужны здесь регулярные выражения, вполне достаточно нахождения подстроки, что быстрее* и проще, чем регулярки:

```
f = open('12345')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open('12345', 'w')
for line in lines:
    if '"deactivated":"banned"' not in line and '"deactivated":"deleted"' not in line:
        f.write(line)
        print(r)
f.close()
```

А исключение у вас не обрабатывается потому, что вы строку, которая его собственно бросает, в try почему-то не обернули.

** Нужно тестировать, конечно. Вполне возможно, что регулярное выражение будет быстрее, чем двойной поиск подстроки.*

Comment: Ошибка... Не совсем то нужно. Нужно чтобы он исключал эти строки, а не выбирал.

Comment: Ну так измените проверку на *not in*. Неужели такие вещи нужно разжевывать? Сейчас обновлю ответ...

Comment: только что не работало...

Comment: Что только что не работало? Я обновил ответ несколько минут назад, изменив логику проверки.

Comment: Да спасибо, увидел) вместо 'or' 'and' стоит. Огромное спасибо за помощь, милсдарь)